# What happens if a warlock kills their patron?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

I was reading Xanathar’s Guide, and the Celestial Warlock subclass is able to choose a unicorn for their patron. However, in the Monster Manual, unicorns only have a CR of 5. So that raised the question: What happens if a warlock kills their patron? Are they unable to level up, do they lose their powers. Or is this another one of those things where nobody from the actual D&D lore has ever been dumb enough to actually try, so it’s just up to the DM?

Comment: Why did Wizards of the Coast write that? This is a good question, I mean, a unicorn getting killed, whether the warlock does it or not, is totally plausible—but it never should have come up because the whole nature of patrons (and clerics’ gods) should be something that isn’t going to get killed in the routine way of things. Unicorns aren’t even immortal, sooner or later it’s going to just die of old age!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!